# Raspberry Pi 4 18.04 SD Card Partition Size on Boot

Tags: 18.04, partitioning, sd-card, raspberrypi, resize

I'd like to limit how large the root partition resizes to on first boot.  I've done this with different flavors of Linux on different boards, but can't seem to find out how for 18.04 on the RPi4. Essentially I'd like the root partition to be 4Gb of a 32Gb card and create a new partition with the unused space after the initial boot.